# Glassfish console not show

Tags: glassfish

I'm new in J2EE and I try some samples, when I try to enter in the  admin console it is in blank, curent location for the redirect login page is

> localhost:4848/j_security_chec

Why? some help please.

Answer (score 0):

Clear your browser's cache and cookies and then go directly to

```
http://localhost:4848
```

and you should be good to go.